# How to renderTextLayer of pdfjs in nodejs for SSR?

Tags: node.js, jsdom, pdf.js

I have tried the pdfjs in browser javascript and it is working fine but if i try to render the textLayer in server side with nodejs it is throw error for canvas.

Anyone know how to make this happen in server side with nodejs?

I asked the same in offical github repo, and they replied it is possible with jsdom. but don't know how to do that
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11011